# Dismissing UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I have code that runs in `searchBarCancelButtonClicked:` I want to run the same code when the user clicks away from the searchbar, even though cancel isn't necessarily clicked.  My current code is below but has an issue that I can't figure out.  I have placed a UIView underneath the search bar that when clicked runs a method that does what I want.

The issue is that when the searchbar is active, the semi-transparent view associated with uisearchbar comes up on top of my view and clicking the view still just dismisses the searchbar, but doesn't run my method.  After the searchbar is dismissed, clicking the view does run my method so I know that is ok.  Basically I need to be able to make the view gesture active while the searchbar is the first responder.

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar*)searchBar {
    UITapGestureRecognizer* singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissSearch:)];
    UIView *transparentView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:transparentViewRect];
    [transparentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [transparentView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [self.view addSubview:transparentView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:transparentView];

    return  YES;

}

- (void) dismissSearch:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{
  //Run my code
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to be notified when the search field becomes focused? There's probably a better way to do that...

Comment: I want to be notified when the searchbar leaves focus

Comment: you can't use the `searchBarShouldEndEditing:`/`searchBarTextDidEndEditing:` delegate method?

Comment: Indeed I can, didn't know that existed.  Thanks!  If you want to post as an answer I will check it off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can probably use the `searchBarShouldEndEditing:` or `searchBarTextDidEndEditing:` delegate methods...

Comment: If you tap at an cell on UITableView result search, the SearchBar is hidden too and.. how I can back to my main view? 

follow Apple doc, this methods on `UISearchDisplayDelegate` should works.. but doesnt.

"when we start/end showing the search UI"
`searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch: / searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:`

Comment: You probably have to set up an action to happen when your search results cells are tapped on--don't think it's automatic.

Answer (score 0):

To solve mentioned issue (when tap on cell at UITablewView with search result), use this condition on `searchBarShouldEndEditing: or searchBarTextDidEndEditing:` methods:

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
  if (self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden) {
        self.searchBar.hidden = true;
  }

  return true;
}
```