# UISearchbar (UISearchResultsUpdating) with Segue does not dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have a problem with a `UISearchBar`. When I search some Text in combination with an `UITableView`, and ill click on one result Cell, the `UISearchBar` is still visible in the next `UIViewController`. the `UISearchbar` is still there (with the Keyword)

So after ill click on one result, ill get (in the next View Controller)but the searchbar and keyboard is still showing.

how can i dismiss the current `UISearchController` so that the search bar and keyboard do not show in the next `UIViewController`?

I have tried:

```
definesPresentationContext = true
```

i have tried to dismiss the `presentingViewController`.

Im doing all of this in the prepared for segue.

My thinking is that I have to dismiss the `UISearchController`...but how can I access it in `preparedForSegue` (in the `searchResultsViewControllers` - this is a `tableViewController` which is used to present the `searchResults`)

Comment: It looks like you're presenting the new controller from the table view controller instead of the search view controller. You should present the next controller from the parent parent, which is the search controller in your case.

Answer (score 2):

You gotta use something like this, forget about the definesPresentationContext

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    searchController.active = false //This will dismiss the searchcontroller, use your own variable for searchController.
    //CALL THE SEGUE YOU WANT BELOW
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code to dismiss the search bar:

```
[yourSearchController.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Is this in the searchResultVC? The UISearchController is instantiated in the ViewController which has all the results. (first one)

Comment: Yes, it is in the first view controller where you do the search. In the prepare for segue dismiss dismiss the search bar by running the code above. When the next view controller shows the search bar will not be there.

Comment: I added that in prepareForSeque and it did not make a difference.

Comment: It worked for me. You may want to try adding the resignFirstResponder method in the searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch: method, or making the search bar not visible. Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736206/dismissing-uisearchbar?rq=1