# UISplitViewController + UISearchController shows search on detail

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, ios9, uisearchcontroller

On iPhone, we have a UISplitViewController.  The master has a search controller in the tableHeaderView.  If we have a search active, when we segue to the detail, the search bar still shows on the detail page.  How do we get rid of that.

Here's the code that adds the search bar in the tableview

```
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
    self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

I tried to resignFirstResponder in prepareForSeque

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Show Event Filter" {
        self.sendEventWithCategory(kAnalyticsCategoryUI_Action, withAction: kAnalyticsActionList_Select, withLabel: "Select filter", withValue: nil, forModuleNamed: self.module?.name)
        let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let detailController = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as! EventsFilterViewController
        detailController.eventModule = self.eventModule
        detailController.hiddenCategories = self.hiddenCategories
        detailController.module = self.module
        detailController.delegate = self
    } else if segue.identifier == "Show Detail" {
        let detailController = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! EventsDetailViewController
        let event = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!) as! Event
        detailController.event = event
        detailController.module = self.module
    }
    self.searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

I've also tried to remove the segue and just call resignFirstResponder in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  It seems resignFirstResponder is not doing anything.  Using Xcode 7 beta 6 (discovered on beta 5).

Comment: See this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181330/uisearchbar-uisearchresultsupdating-with-segue-does-not-dismiss/32187637#32187637

Comment: I had already tried that in prepareForSegue but that did not fix it.

Comment: Could you post the code you used in prepareForSegue?

Comment: Just for kicks try moving resignFirstResponder to the beginning of the prepareForSegue method. I'm not running the Beta so I won't be able to help beyond this.

Comment: I took out the segue and moved the resignFirstResponder to didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  I also rearranged the lines in prepareForSegue.  Its as if resignFirstResponder is not doing anything.

Comment: We have a bar button that also shows a modal controller.  That correctly "covers" the UISearchBar.  But the "show detail" segue is the problem.

Comment: I created a new project from xcode's master-detail template.  I added a search bar as I showed in the code above, and then implemented an empty updateSearchResultsForSearchController.  In prepareForSegue I call self.searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder() and this project also shows the same behavior.

Comment: You could try:       UITextField *textSearchField = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"]; and resignFirstResponder on the text field. It's a hack but it may permit you to move forward until the beta is fixed.

Comment: @Gjchoza I tried that hack but that also did not do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. Fixed this issue by adding the following code to my Master View Controller on viewDidLoad:
`self.definesPresentationContext = true`

Comment: I forgot to come back and update this.  We found that works, but causes a new issue when we hit back to the master list on iphone, when we have translucency turned off in the navigation bars.